# Low Graphics Mode when installing on old COMPAQ computer

Tags: system-installation

I am very new to Linux and Ubuntu. I have an obsolete brand of computer with these specs: Compaq Presario-SR1500NX, 3000+AMD Processor, 256MB-PC2700 memory, 80GB-7200RPM hard drive.

I am stuck with the "Low Graphics Mode" box and have yet to find an answer that works for me. I wiped my hard drive and installed Ubuntu, thinking it would work fine. So, now, I just have Ubuntu OS that won't work. Is my system compatible and if not, what WILL work as an operating system? I'm not computer savvy so thorough explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For the low graphics mode, the only solution is to install a video driver for your graphic card.

You can lower system resource usage by installing all XFCE4 packages including XFCE4-settings, and also Xubuntu-desktop and Xubuntu-settings packages.

This way you'll be able to choose the XFCE session (or Xubuntu session) at login prompt, and use fewer resources than you are using now when you can access only the Gnome session in Ubuntu. If you install XFCE4 packages dont forget to also install the **xfce4-goodies** package.

You can also choose to install all LXDE packages, LXDE package included, and also Lubuntu-desktop and lubuntu-settings packages. This way you'll be able to also choose the LXDE session (Lubuntu session) at login prompt. Lxde session uses even fewer resources than the Xfce session.

You can install all these packages using Synaptic Package Manager, and type in the Search field either **xfce4** or **lxde** to find and install all required packages for each session. If you don't have Synaptic present on your systen, you can install it using this code:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

To make your system a little bit faster, I suggest you also install **preload** package:

```
sudo apt-get install preload
```

And also you can install **bum** package which will allow you to stop some daemons and services that you know you never use, like printers, scanners and so on:

```
sudo apt-get install bum
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the Via Unichrome integrated graphics or a discrete GPU? If using discrete go into your BIOS settings and back down memory usage or disable the onboard graphics. This will free up system memory for the OS to use. From the looks of your system though I would agree with floppy. XFCE desktop would be better suited to a system with your specs.

Comment: I have no clue to answer your question. Don't even know what a GPU is. But, in following this advice, would I not need an operating system at work on the computer for internet access to install these suggestions? I replaced XP instead of using it along side Ubuntu. Dumb, I now realize.

Comment: Sorry, GPU= Graphics processing unit. It is what outputs the video signal. My guess is that you are probably using the integrated (built in) rather than a discrete (added in stand alone graphics card). I would go with floppy's suggestion at installing the XFCE desktop rather than Gnome (what you have now). It takes less hardware and resource to run. My suggestion also to look around and see if you can find some more system memory.If the system in question can boot to desktop and access the internet, you can use it to do the above.Just follow floppy's tutorial and you should be fine.

Comment: Could I burn that (XFCE) to a disc as I did with Ubuntu? Then, install it with the disk? Then, go from there with the other installations such as the "goodies" package?

Comment: Yes, you can. Looking at system specs and OS requirements I am more inclined that you would be better off using [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) with a alternate installer than a live cd. Lubuntu uses even less resource than [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/)

Comment: [Lubuntu alternate install](http://cdimages.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/saucy/release/lubuntu-13.10-alternate-i386.iso)------ [Xubuntu alternate install](http://mirror.anl.gov/pub/ubuntu-iso/CDs-Xubuntu/12.04/release/xubuntu-12.04.4-alternate-i386.iso)

Comment: When you say "alternate" installer, do you mean such as a USB stick? Yah, my pet dinosaur won't boot from USB. Tried it when I was putting Ubuntu on. And are you saying I can have just as much fun with Lubuntu and the resource friendly OS's mentioned? Web surfing, music downloading, and whatnot?

Comment: A alternate installer does not have all the "eye candy" that a live cd does. In other words you do not see a "desktop". Pretty much like installing Windows Xp and prior. It is pretty straight forward. You can burn the image to disc just as you did before and boot from it. Yes you will be able to do all the above.